# SwiftUI How to trigger action inside View when view appers / dissapears?

Tags: swiftui

I have recently started dabbling in `swiftUI`. One of the thing that I have noticed is that now we have option to add modifier on View: `.onAppear` and `.onDisappear`, and trigger some action. But what I want to do is somewhat different, I want to trigger action inside the View when View appears / disappears.

For example I have video player and every time inside List view scrolls from the screen, I want to pause video (Video is embedded inside my view). And vice versa I want video to start playing. All logic for video playing / pausing is inside the view.

So how can I trigger action when view appears / disappears?

Here is my code example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(0..<14) { item in
                VideoPreviewView(videoURLString: largeVideos[item])
                    .frame(height: 375)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .onAppear {
                        // play video
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        // stop video
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now how do I pass `VideoPreviewView` these actions, player is inside the `VideoPreviewView`?

Comment: This is exactly what ‘onAppear’ is doing. You could run startVideo() (a function “inside” the view) within onAppear. Also you should provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Ali, i will update question

Comment: You would add the `.onAppear` modifier inside the `VideoPreviewView` view body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run `onAppear` logic, when a child view appears you simply attach the `.onAppear` function inside the child views body.

```
struct VideoPreviewView: View {
    let videoURLString: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("VideoPreviewView")
            .onAppear {
                playVideo()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                stopVideo()
            }
    }

    private func playVideo() {
        print("Start playing \(videoURLString)")
    }

    private func stopVideo() {
        print("Stop playing \(videoURLString)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let videoUrls = ["1","2","3", "4","5", "6", "7"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(videoUrls, id: \.self) { urlString in
                LazyVStack {
                    VideoPreviewView(videoURLString: urlString)
                        .frame(height: 375)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which yields the following output in the console:

```
Start playing 1
Start playing 2
Start playing 3
Start playing 4
Start playing 5
Start playing 6
Start playing 7
Stop playing 4
Stop playing 5
Stop playing 6
Stop playing 7
```

All `onAppear` methods of the child views are called, and right after the the `onDisappear` methods of the non-visible child views are called.
You can find a discussion on whats happening here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/onappear-something-i-don-t-understand/1978

If you use a `ScrollView` + `ForEach` + `LazyVStack` (this one is important) combination, you get the following output:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let videoUrls = ["1","2","3", "4","5", "6", "7"]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(videoUrls, id: \.self) { urlString in
                LazyVStack {
                    VideoPreviewView(videoURLString: urlString)
                        .frame(height: 375)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Start playing 3
Start playing 2
Start playing 1
```

Now only the visible ChildViews are called. If you scroll down you shoudl see your desired output in the console. This should be applicable for your use case.

All code was tested and run with Xcode 12.4 and iOS 14.4

Comment: Actually I can't reproduce your second example, all .onAppear are called immediately, not just first three. Can you recheck?

Comment: After further testing this looks like SwiftUI bug. I will open new thread about this one

Comment: I added the full code for the content view. It is important that you use a **LazyVStack**.

Comment: This is brilliant! I've had issues with onAppear being called immediately on load because I had to use a ScrollView + VStack for my purpose. Wrapping the element I wanted to trigger the onAppear in a separate LazyVStack solved my issue. Thanks!